How do we have a bijection between a set and a number?
In this comment a definition of "finite" is given as:

In bijection with an ordinal which is less than every non-zero limit
ordinal.

It seems that the word "ordinal" is used in two different meanings. This is confusing to me.
The first "ordinal" means an ordinal set.
An ordinal set is defined as:

A well-ordered set where any non-empty subset has a least element.

Let's call the given set that we are testing for finiteness $\mathbf{A}$. Let's call the ordinal set $\mathbf{B}$.
$\mathbf{A}$ is put in bijection with $\mathbf{B}$.
The ordinal set $\mathbf{B}$ has the property that it is less than every non-zero limit ordinal.
Here "limit ordinal" is a number, an ordinal number, not an ordinal set.
Can you explain how a set is said to be less than every non-zero limit ordinal (number)? And how does a set $\mathbf{A}$ is put into bijection with an ordinal number. I realize I have a confusion about terminology. Can you clarify?
As far as I can understand this definition seems to say that a finite set has a beginning (well-ordered) and an end (limit ordinal). Is this correct?

In set theory, everything is a set. Particular sets are chosen to represent numbers.

Ok. Usually, bijection can be shown as a figure. Can we draw a figure of what is going on here so that I can understand it?

In what way you count the eggs in a basket? Take one egg from the basket and associate itt to number 1. Then consider the remaining eggs: take an egg from them and associate it to number 2, and so on. It is called counting.

Your definition of "an ordinal set" is not complete. You must specify that the strict ordering is $\in$.

"Here "limit ordinal" is a number, an ordinal number, not an ordinal set": "ordinal sets" is your own (unusual) name for "ordinal numbers" (which are actually sets, by your definition above).

@AnneBauval I cannot understand your sentence "You must specify that the strict ordering is ∈." I read it as: "You must specify that the strict ordering is [element of]" which does not make sense to me. Can you explain or give a complete definition of "ordinal set"?

The definition of ordinal "number" (which you keep calling "ordinal set") is available here: "A set S is an ordinal if and only if S is strictly well-ordered with respect to set membership [emphasis is mine] and every element of S is also a subset of S"

This is in the context of set theory and Von Neumann ordinals. A limit ordinal is a set.
Some definitions:

$0=\{\}$ (the empty set) is an ordinal


If $n$ is an ordinal then $n+1=\{n\}\cup n$ is a successor ordinal; an example is $5=\{4\}\cup 4=\{4,3,2,1,0\}$ because $4=\{3,2,1,0\}$.


If $n$ is an ordinal but neither 0 nor a successor ordinal then it is a limit ordinal. For instance, $\omega=\aleph_0=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\dots\}$ is a limit ordinal.

To put a set $S$ into bijection with the ordinal $5$ means to match every $s\in S$ to a unique value from $5=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. That is to say, $S$ can be put in bijection with $5$ if and only if $|S|=5$ i.e. $S$ contains exactly 5 things.
Well-ordering is not just about "a beginning", but about a beginning (smallest element) and a successor (next) function. We can say the least element of the whole set, then we can remove that least and ask for the next least, and so on.
This makes sense for finite sets but somewhat unintuitively it also makes sense for infinite sets like $\omega+\omega=\{0,1,2,3,4,\dots,\omega,\omega+1,\omega+2,\omega+3,\dots\}$ where it takes (informally) infinitely many successor applications to get through the list (after infinitely many applications we are left with $\{\omega+3,\omega+4,\omega+5,\dots\}$, which has least element $\omega+3$).
A limit ordinal does not have an "end" (largest element) - in fact this is precisely what makes it a limit ordinal.

"$\cup$ is used in a slightly different way to what you might be used to": no,  there is no alternative way.

Thanks for taking my question seriously and answering. Your answer was very helpful. I'm sure it will be helpful to others too. But one question: In what sense this is a definition of "finite"? It looks more like a definition of "infinite". Thanks again.

@zeynel if you have a definition of "infinite" then "finite" is defined as "not infinite".

I'm sorry the question is closed but I have more questions. I don't think your answer defines infinity. When you write "infinite sets" you assume "infinite" without defining it.

Also ordinals is about order of sets but in elementary set theory we defined set as an unordered collection. Do we use a different definition of set in higher mathematics?

@zeynel A set $S$ is finite iff there exists some $n\in \omega$ such that $S$ is in bijection to $n$. If you are using an ordinal to measure the size of an ordering (a set plus a "less than" relation) it must be through some restriction on the bijection (e.g. an order isomorphism) because, as you say, sets are unordered.

As far as I understand, we have a given set $\mathbf{S}$ that we want to test if it is finite. We try a bijection with another set $\mathbf{S’}$ and if we have a bijection we say that $\mathbf{S}$ is finite. But this cannot be a definition of finite. We assumed that $\mathbf{S’}$ was finite, whatever “finite” means we don’t know, we never defined it. All we know is that $\mathbf{S}$ and $\mathbf{S’}$ are bijective. What am I missing here?
